# Rails override nested friendly_id in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, friendly-id

I'm using the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to handle slugs in my Rails 4 app.  For simplicity's sake, let's say I have two resources, **Missions** and **Tasks**.  **Tasks** are nested inside **Missions**.  Both models are using FriendlyId, and the slugs are working fine.  Because a **Task** belongs to a **Mission**, a **Task** has a **mission_id** on it.

I'm running into a problem when I update a **Task**.  Because the **mission_id** is coming through the parameters as a slug (a friendly_id string and not an integer id), the **mission_id** on the **Task** is being updated as **0**, because it's expecting an integer and is being passed a string.

Anyone have any ideas on how to address this?

routes.rb

```
resources :missions do
  resources :tasks
end
```

Mission.rb

```
class Mission < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  belongs_to :mission
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Include `finders`:

```
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

From doc:

```
Finders are no longer overridden by default. If you want to do friendly finds,
you must do Model.friendly.find rather than Model.find. You can however 
restore FriendlyId 4-style finders by using the :finders addon
```

This is for version 5.